# vite startup over 20s on Apple M1 Max

Tags: node.js, networking, vite

I just started a new vite project `npm create vite@latest` and it takes over 20s to start. [image: Local:]

I'm running on Apple M1 Max. I wonder if someone could help me here?
my `node` version is `v20.4.0` and my `npm` version is `9.7.2`

steps to reproduce:

- `npm create vite@latest`
- select vanilla/javascript
- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`

This is the produced `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^4.4.2"
  }
}
```

the same projects takes a `460ms` on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rpg8az?file=main.js)

edit:

I had some interesting insights. First I started to debug the `vite` command. Note that I have not added any parameters to the CLI command.

At some point during the `startServer` from vite it attempts to resolve the hostname.

```
const hostname = await resolveHostname(options.host);
```

Since I did not pass in an option for the host, this evaluates to

```
 await resolveHostname(undefined)
```

This behaviour leads to a fallback to `localhost`. So I did a little test and ran a node httpserver with host `localhost`.

```
import { promises } from 'node:dns';

import http from 'node:http'

let now = performance.now();

const nodeResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promises.lookup('localhost').then((result) => {
        resolve(result.address)
    })
})
let timeTaken = performance.now() - now;
console.log(`ip lookup done after ${timeTaken} ms`);

now = performance.now();
http.createServer().listen(3000, "localhost", () => {
    timeTaken = performance.now() - now;
    console.log(`server started after ${timeTaken} ms`);
})
```

That takes on my machine a little over `10 seconds`.

Using a `host` now as option, for example `npx vite --host 127.0.0.1`, reduces the start time of `105ms`. So far so good.

I guess that some configuration on my machine is off, but I'm not a network expert. So definitely still looking for answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `dns.lookup` under the hood prioritizes ipv6. But I didnt have a configuration for that. So adding

```
::1             localhost
```

to `/etc/hosts` solves the problem.

Related issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47785